How to self-contained publish WPF when referencing Asp .Net Core Web Api?
This can be discovered by creating a minimal example:

creating an WPF application and then a new Asp .Net Core Web Api project in the solution.
If WPF does not reference Asp .Net core, it can be published self-contained without any problems, once it does it will fail to publish.

I tried to add reference for WPF which the only nuget package ‘Swashbuckle.AspNetCore’ in Asp.Net core, and changed the AnyCPU in Configuration to x64 same as Target runtime, but that didn't prevent the failure.
C# is version 6.0.

Why you need to reference Asp .Net core in WPF? if your answer that you have a shared objects\Models..., then you have to create class library instead.

@MustafaMutasim Oh indeed it was a stupid mistake, after I changed the Asp.net core output type to class library it worked fine. I'd like to mark your answer to close it but this is a comment...

Great!  you can add the answer by yourself no worries, I do not have more details to be included.

Are you referencing ASP.NEt Core as a project, like a library or a NuGet package? have a look at this SO Question if you are fairly new to this kind of thing, just ask

@XAMlMAX Thanks for the suggestion, maybe I'll try to use that for a new project after that.

Thanks @MustafaMutasim for the comment, it worked fine after I changed the Asp.net core output type to class library...
